# Set new reactive properties in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component that pass a config object as `props` to its child.

I wish to add set reactive entries to this object, for example:

```
 created() {
   this.config.page = this.config.page || 1
 }
```

So from this moment, the changes for `page` will be reactive.
Is it possible?

A not successful attempt:

```
beforeCreate() {
  if(!this.$options.propsData.config.page){
    Vue.set(this.$options.propsData.config, 'page', 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it from `beforeCreated` to `created`.  This should work for you I think:

```
 create() {
   if(!this.$options.propsData.config.page){
     Vue.set(this.$options.propsData.config, 'page', 1)
   }else{
      this.config.page = 1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Well, it worked, even with beforeCreate() hook. I can see the gettes and setters for `page`; but now, even tough the object gets updated, another component that uses the same config object is not reacting to those changes (with {{config.page}}) template wise. pfff.. what a nightmare!

Comment: That probably deserves it's own question.